# How to update iOS on iPad 4?

Tags: ios, upgrade

My iPad isn't updating its iOS version (10.3.4). How do I fix this?

My iPad is the iPad 4 (doesn't show option to update).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [iPad 4](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/ipad/specs/apple-ipad-a1458-4th-gen-late-2012-wi-fi-only-specs.html) can only be upgraded up to iOS 10.3.4, it will not show an option to upgrade to iOS 11 or later.